# Swift: Any benefit in specifying .0 after an explicitly declared float type

Tags: swift

In Swift, if a type is already declared as `float` or `CGFloat`, is there any benefit still in assigning a number ending with `.0` to it?

In a team setting, would you allow float values without `.0` be committed?

e.g.

```
var test: CGFloat = 0
```

versus

```
var test: CGFloat = 0.0
```

or

```
view.alpha = 0
```

versus

```
view.alpha = 0.0
```

Comment: While the second half of your question is entirely subjective, I'm always declaring my floats without `.0`, just for avoiding unnecessary characters.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler doesn’t care yet it makes the code and your intention a little clearer. That’s basically all there is to it.